# Create a file switching user in the same process

Tags: windows, delphi

I have a program that needs to create a file in a directory where the user who is running the application doesn't has permission to write, but other user has. Is possible to do that?

I know that I can login a user with write privileges in that folder with LogonUserA, but then I don't know how to create a file using the returned token. Also, I know the user name and password of the user who can write in that directory.

I use Delphi, but the example or ideas could be in any language.

Answer (score 0):

```
HANDLE hToken = LogonUser(...);
ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(hToken);
// do something
RevertToSelf();
CloseHandle(hToken);
```